# Using Segment Controller to "Push" rather than UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I've involved myself so much in NavigationControllers that I've become kinda ignorant with other options. 
Here's what I want to accomplish, I've built Subclassed ViewControllers to Push via NavigationController that works pretty fine.

However, to avoid the Idea of going back and getting to a new view  doesn't fit  for quick access since this is about calculator, I came up with using SegmentedControl.

I added UISegmentControl to the NavigationBar. 
What I want to accomplish, is on tapping of a segment, The Calculator1ViewController Loads below the NavigationBar. And on tapping another Segment, the previous ViewController is unloaded and a different "Calculator2ViewController" is loaded.

I'm not quite sure how to do it, loadFromNib may not work too well, because I'm using custom ViewControllers.

Any suggestions would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off making it a single view controller, and just swapping out the views.